# Dual-Boot MacBook Pro 2015 stuck loading into GNU GRUB version 2.04

Tags: macos, terminal, network, unix, grub

a while ago I decided to dual boot Ubuntu onto my Macbook but recently decided to remove the partition. This has caused the Mac to only boot into GNU GRUB version 2.04.

While I know internet recovery is an option, I am at my school which requires an additional confirmation to access the Wi-Fi or registration of the devices MAC address on our IOT website. This is my main issue, no matter what command I try I'm not able to see my devices MAC address from the GRUB terminal. Is this something that is even possible, or will I have to wait until I have access to a different internet to initiate the internet recovery?

Answer (score 0):

If you used the Disk Utility or `diskutil` command to remove a Linux partition, then there is a fairly good chance the type for the partition containing macOS was changed to `FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF`. Apparently, you did not remove the Ubuntu boot (GRUB) files from the EFI partition. When you boot your Mac, the firmware will only detect these Ubuntu boot files which is why your Mac is booting to GRUB. Since the partition containing macOS is the wrong type, you will not be allowed to boot to regular macOS Recovery. Booting to Internet Recovery is not the only way to correct the partition type. For example, you can make a bootable Ubuntu Live flash drive. After booting from the flash drive, you can use the `gdisk` command to correct type partition type. Note that `gdisk` uses codes to represent type partition type GUIDs. In your case, you will want the code for APFS which is `AF0A`. Or, you can enter the actual APFS GUID of `7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC`.

---

### How to Use the `gdisk` Command

1. Enter the `lsblk` command. From the output, determine the name of the internal drive where Ubuntu is installed. This usually will be either `sda` or `nvme0n1`. Here I will assume `nvme0n1`.
2. Enter the following command. If your name from from the previous step is different from `nvme0n1`, then make the appropriate substitution.

   ```
   sudo gdisk /dev/nvme0n1
   ```
3. The `gdisk` command is interactive. Enter the values shown in the first column of the table.

   | Entry | Type | Comment |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | `p` | command | Print the partition table |
   | `t` | command | Change a partition's type code |
   | `2` | parameter | Partition number (If your partition number is different, then make the appropriate substitution.) |
   | `af0a` | parameter | Hex code |
   | `w` | command | Write table to disk and exit |
   | `y` | parameter | Confirm to proceed |

Comment: Hello, sorry but I am just now seeing your response. I've got a live version of Ubuntu running but I'm really not sure how gdisk works at all, I'm inexperienced with command line/Linux in general. When typing in `gdisk AF0A` it tells me Problem opening AF0A for reading! Error is 2. The specified file does not exist

Did I delete the MacOS files or am I not understanding the command?

Comment: @cb98: I updated my answer.